# If statement is not working with grep command

Tags: bash, if-statement, unix, grep

I have this statement in bash

```
if grep -Fq "$abc" $resultsfile && [ "flag" == 'N' ]
```

I am running the same command for different sets of values. But for one particular value set alone this command is not working.

When I try to print this If statement using a variable for this impacted value set, the result is as follows.

Ie.

```
echo "if grep -Fq "$abc" $resultsfile && [ "flag" == 'N' ]"
== 'N' ]Fq 1234 file.csv && [ N
```

While for other value sets Iam getting a proper If statement..

What could be causing this?

I have tried reducing the fila name length, and when I split the If statement into two, it is working, but still its strange because command is working for other value sets. This shell script is invoked for multiple source systems

Comment: Use `set -x` instead of trying to print the command

Comment: what do you think the `-F` option is doing in your call to `grep`? AND please edit your question to have the `abc=???` value that is causing the problem. Good luck.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not really comparing `"flag"` to `'N'`, because those are two string literals and will never be identical. It looks like whatever string you use instead of `flag` ends with a carriage return.

Comment: That command line is **not** a **complete AND functional construct**.

Comment: I presume you want `[ "flag" == 'N' ]` to be `[ "$flag" = N ]`? The use of `==` is a nonstandard extension that not all shells support (the standard string comparison operator is just `=`), and `flag` and `N` will never be equal to each other because they're two different strings.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure **how** that command worked for you *for any other case*.  NOTE: you are missing the "**$**" in front of **flag**.

For the case of **abc="1234"**, the only way that logic **could be made to work** is if it looked like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

flag="N"
abc="1234"
resultsfile="file.csv"

cat >"${resultsfile}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
dumdum 1235
google 1234
champion 1236
EnDoFiNpUt

if [[ $(grep -Fq "$abc" $resultsfile; echo $?) -eq 0 && "${flag}" == 'N' ]] 
then
    echo "hello"
else
    echo "goodbye"
fi
```

Comment: why wrap `grep -q` inside redundant `[[ .. ]]` ?

Comment: You may be correct.  I usually only program with ash and single square brackets, using my preferred mode of backquotes !  :-)

Comment: Grep manual says "Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found", which is what I believe the requestor intended.

Comment: `if [[ $(grep -q foo /dev/null) -eq 0 ]]; then echo hmmm; fi`

Comment: `if grep -q foo /dev/null; then :; else echo better; fi`

Comment: `if grep -Fq "$abc" "$resultsfile" && [[ $flag = N ]]; then` is much better practice. No reason to put your `grep` inside a test statement and then test the exit status of the test when you could just test the exit status of grep directly.

Comment: To jhnc and Charles Duffy ... I appreciate and acknowledge what you both have said as being correct.  However, this ancient brain prefers things which, to my eyes, are more verbosely explicit (to me) and not as implicit.  I need logic that is "in my face" and that I will not misunderstand.  That is my approach, admittedly not always the most efficient.